# O/R Mapping: One-to-One Id Column

Tags: database, orm

I have to create two tables and objects with a one-to-one relationship. Now I am wondering if it is better to use a foreign key in one of the tables, or whether I should use the primary key of the first table as the primary key of the second table.

Any hints/advices?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the tables? Can rows in either of the tables exist with no corresponding row in the other? If not, why not just have one table?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by no corresponding row. I would prefer two tables for two reasons: first the two tables reflect two types, second, there is a small chance that the one-to-one relationship will change in a one-to-many relationship (yagni?)

Answer (score -1):

I can't offer specific advice - I'm able to avoid questions like this in my own project because I use Fluent NHibernate (FNH) Automapping.

With FNH, you can automatically generate a database schema from an object model.

It will generate primary and foreign keys as necessary - I don't even have to think about it.

If your application will only have two tables, FNH is probably not worth the trouble, but for larger real world databases, I find it a much more productive way to work.